# List all directories and subdirectories, excluding directories without files

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, ls, directory-listing

I would like to list all the directories and sub directories in and below the current path. Since I only wanted to display directories I came up with the following command:

```
find -type d -exec ls -d1 {} \; | cut -c 3-
```

This prints out for example

```
webphone
music
finance
finance/banking
finance/realestate
finance/trading
finance/other
finance/moneylending
finance/insurance
webradio
webtv
```

The problem I have right now is, that the directory `finance` is listed. `finance` contains no files, just the sub directories you see above. What I want to achieve is the following output:

```
webphone
music
finance/banking
finance/realestate
finance/trading
finance/other
finance/moneylending
finance/insurance
webradio
webtv
```

In this list the directory `finance` is not listed. Therefore I need your advice of how to filter directories which contain no files (only subdirectories).

Comment: why are you using `find -type d -exec ls -d1 {} \;` instead of `ls -d1 */`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way: list all regular files, strip away the file basenames, and remove duplicates.

```
find . -type f | sed 's!/[^/]*$!!' | sort -u
```

If you want to strip the leading `./`:

```
find . -type f | sed -e 's!/[^/]*$!!' -e 's!^\./!!' | sort -u
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your reg-exp search was nearly perfect. I just had to strip the "./" and to remove the first emtpy line. The command I run now is: find . -type f | sed 's!/[^/]*$!!' | sort -u | sed '1d' | cut -c 3-

Comment: @ftiaronsem: the empty line corresponds to the current directory. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

I consider installing tree:

- sudo apt-get install tree

and then run

- tree -d /path/to/start/dir

to display directories only.

**Example:**

```
root@X100e:~# tree -d /var/cache/
/var/cache/
├── apache2
│   └── mod_disk_cache
├── apt
│   └── archives
│       └── partial
├── binfmts
├── cups
│   └── rss
├── debconf
├── dictionaries-common
├── flashplugin-installer
...
```

Answer (score 0):

[`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) has an `-empty` option that you can use directly

```
find . -type d ! -empty
```

Comment: But this will show directories that have subdirectories but don’t contain any files — and the OP wants these to be treated as empty.  Also, please don’t teach people to use ``-not`` without at least mentioning the original (and POSIX-compliant) “not” operator, namely **`!`**.